# Need to open text file, print random word with over 5 characters python

Tags: python, file, random

```
import random
dictionary = open('word_list.txt', 'r')
for line in dictionary:

    for i in range(0, len(line)):
        if i >= 5:    
            word = random.choice(line)
dictionary.close()
```

1. this code doesnt seem to work for me
2. here is a link to the file if it helps
   http://vlm1.uta.edu/~athitsos/courses/cse1310_summer2013/assignments/assignment8/word_list.txt

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

with open('word_list.txt', 'r') as f:
    words = [word.rstrip() for word in f if len(word) > 5]

print random.choice(words)
```

As @ashwini-chaudhary correctly pointed out, `word` on each step of iteration has newline `\n` at the end - that's why you need to use `rstrip()`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each word is on it's own line such as:

```
word
word2
word3
...
```

then you can do this:

```
from random import choice
with open("word_list.txt") as file:
    print choice([line.rstrip() for line in file if len(line) > 5])
```